# jQuery plug-in doesn't work

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, plugins

I have read a lot about jQuery plug-ins and have tried to make something for my own website. It is my first script and basically it was just for fun.. Somehow the plugin does not work..

this is my plugin

```
 ;(function($){

     // We name the function mouser
     $.fn.mouser = function(options) {

         // Default settings - can be replaced by options
         var defaults = {
             mouse: "click"     // click is an event that contains both the mousedown and mouse up event in one.
         }

         // Extend the options and defaults to variables
         var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

         // Now start the Function
         return this.each(function() {

             // The original element is defined with a variable
             var element = $(this)

             // We have to define the functions that has to react based on the option 'mouse'
             // So if it is - as standard - set to 'click'
             if (opts.mouse == "click") {

                 // ... we want to do a 'click'-function (Basic jQuery)
                 // when the element is clicked
                 element.click(function(e) {

                     // ... we ensure which mouse button has been pressed
                     switch (e.which) {

                         // ... and execute a function based on that information

                         // Left Mouse Button
                         case 1: {left_mouse_command(); return false;}

                         // Middle Mouse Button
                         case 2: {middle_mouse_command(); return false;}

                         // Right Mouse Button
                         case 3: {right_mouse_command(); return false;}

                     };

                 });

             // Else if 'mouse' is set to 'mouseup'
             } else if (opts.mouse == "mouseup") {

                 // ... we want to do a 'mouseup'-function (Basic jQuery)
                 // when the mouse is released from the element
                 element.mouseup(function(e) {

                     // ... we ensure which mouse button has been pressed
                     switch (e.which) {

                         // ... and execute a function based on that information

                         // Left Mouse Button
                         case 1: {left_mouse_command(); return false;}

                         // Middle Mouse Button
                         case 2: {middle_mouse_command(); return false;}

                         // Right Mouse Button
                         case 3: {right_mouse_command(); return false;}

                     };

                 });

             // Else if 'mouse' is set to 'mousedown'
             } else if (opts.mouse == "mousedown") {

                 // ... we want to do a 'mousedown'-function (Basic jQuery)
                 // when the mouse begins to click on the element
                 element.mousedown(function(e) {

                     // ... we ensure which mouse button has been pressed
                     switch (e.which) {

                         // ... and execute a function based on that information

                         // Left Mouse Button
                         case 1: {left_mouse_command(); return false;}

                         // Middle Mouse Button
                         case 2: {middle_mouse_command(); return false;}

                         // Right Mouse Button
                         case 3: {right_mouse_command(); return false;}

                     };
                 }); 
             };
         });
     };
 })(jQuery);
```

Then I call the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(document).mouser();

    function left_mouse_command() {
        alert('You clicked with the left mouse button');
    }

    function middle_mouse_command() {
        alert('You clicked with the middle mouse button');
    }

    function right_mouse_command() {
        alert('You clicked with the right mouse button');
    }
});
```

anybody who can find the mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `xxxxxx_mouse_command()` are out of scope for the plug-in. You should move them from `$(document).ready()` to the global scope.

EDIT: The last command for each `case` should be `break;` and not `return false;`. You should instead put a `e.preventDefault()` to the end of each handler. You don't need to wrap your `case` commands in {} brackets

Some of the semicolons are missing and you have added some "unusual" semicolons at the end of switch and if statements

Try this

```
;(function($){

 // We name the function mouser
 $.fn.mouser = function(options) {

     // Default settings - can be replaced by options
     var defaults = {
         mouse: "click"     // click is an event that contains both the mousedown and mouse up event in one.
     };

     // Extend the options and defaults to variables
     var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

     // Now start the Function
     return this.each(function() {

         // The original element is defined with a variable
         var element = $(this);

         // We have to define the functions that has to react based on the option 'mouse'
         // So if it is - as standard - set to 'click'
         if (opts.mouse == "click") {

             // ... we want to do a 'click'-function (Basic jQuery)
             // when the element is clicked
             element.click(function(e) {

                 // ... we ensure which mouse button has been pressed
                 switch (e.which) {

                     // ... and execute a function based on that information

                     // Left Mouse Button
                     case 1: left_mouse_command(); break;

                     // Middle Mouse Button
                     case 2: middle_mouse_command(); break;

                     // Right Mouse Button
                     case 3: right_mouse_command(); break;

                 }

                 e.preventDefault();

             });

         // Else if 'mouse' is set to 'mouseup'
         } else if (opts.mouse == "mouseup") {

             // ... we want to do a 'mouseup'-function (Basic jQuery)
             // when the mouse is released from the element
             element.mouseup(function(e) {

                 // ... we ensure which mouse button has been pressed
                 switch (e.which) {

                     // ... and execute a function based on that information

                     // Left Mouse Button
                     case 1: left_mouse_command(); break;

                     // Middle Mouse Button
                     case 2: middle_mouse_command(); break;

                     // Right Mouse Button
                     case 3: right_mouse_command(); break;

                 }
                 e.preventDefault();
             });

         // Else if 'mouse' is set to 'mousedown'
         } else if (opts.mouse == "mousedown") {

             // ... we want to do a 'mousedown'-function (Basic jQuery)
             // when the mouse begins to click on the element
             element.mousedown(function(e) {

                 // ... we ensure which mouse button has been pressed
                 switch (e.which) {

                     // ... and execute a function based on that information

                     // Left Mouse Button
                     case 1: left_mouse_command(); break;

                     // Middle Mouse Button
                     case 2: middle_mouse_command(); break;

                     // Right Mouse Button
                     case 3: right_mouse_command(); break;

                 }
                 e.preventDefault();
             }); 
         }
     });
 }
})(jQuery);
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).mouser();
});

function left_mouse_command() {
    alert('You clicked with the left mouse button');
}

function middle_mouse_command() {
    alert('You clicked with the middle mouse button');
}

function right_mouse_command() {
    alert('You clicked with the right mouse button');
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. it made the plug-in work.. but there is just one thing about the `right_mouse_command`.. Somehow the `e.preventDefault();` doesn't stop the modal box from opening when you right click.